# Do you know what's issue of my code, NDsolve and ParametricPlot

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

Could you please point out my isse of the code?
Frustrated.

```
s = NDSolve[{r'[t] = (0.2)*r[t] - (0.002) r[t]*w[t], 
   w'[t] = (-0.1)*w[t] + (0.001)*r[t]*w[t], w[0] = 25, 
   r[0] = 100}, {w, r}, {t, 0, 200}]
{{w -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 200.}}, "<>"],
  r -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 200.}}, "<>"]}}
Plot[{w[t] /. s, r[t] /. s}, {t, 0, 200}]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{r[t], w[t]} /. s], {t，0, 200}]
```

[image]

fixed pic
[image]

Comment: Refresh the kernel and replace `=` with `==`.

Comment: @Kuba, Thx. Btw, I am supposed to see another circle plot by using ParametricPlot, but right now there is only one plot. Do you know why? Thx for you time

Comment: replace `{t，0, 200}` with `{t, 0, 200}` in the last line.

Comment: @kglr, thx my bad